# warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

I will just keep things simple:

Here is the function I built, which will create a new dnode:

```
struct dnode *dnode_create() {
        return calloc(1, sizeof(struct dnode));
    }
```

and here is how I call it:

```
struct dnode *newnode = dnode_create();
```

I don't understand how this involved with integer?

Comment: lemme guess; using visual studio?

Comment: Ahhh.  C99 did away with implicit int, but gcc still allows it.

Comment: So you mean if I switch to  another compiler it may wont complain about this?

Comment: It will *rightly* complain because your code is wrong. I would prefer a compiler error (set -Werror on gcc)

Comment: try  return `(struct dnode *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct dnode));`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast". But I don't think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980142/warning-initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast-but-i-dont)

Comment: @LidongGuo: That is wrong in two ways. first, it doesn't address the issue here.  Second, you never cast the return value of malloc in C.  There is no benefit and it can actually hide an error (the error being experienced here it just so happens).  You are proposing to introduce a more egregious error to silence a warning.

Comment: If you're compiling with GCC, then you should also compile with the options `-Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition`.  This will ensure that all (non-static) functions (except `main()`, which doesn't need one) have a prototype declaration in scope before you define or use the function.  You likely didn't `#include <stdlib.h>` where you define `dnode_create()`, or you didn't the appropriate header (perhaps `#include "dnode.h"`) where you tried to use `dnode_create()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either `calloc` or `dnode_create` doesn't have a prototype in view when you try to use it.

That means it assumes an `int` return type, hence your warning message.

To ensure a prototype for `calloc` is in view, include the `stdlib.h` header file.

If it's the `dnode_create`, you have to do it yourself, by either:

- defining the function before you use it (in a given source file); or
- declaring a prototype before you use it.

Expanding on that, both of these will work, assuming they're sequenced this way in a single translation unit (simplistically, source file). First:

```
struct dnode *dnode_create (void) {         // declare & define
    return calloc(1, sizeof(struct dnode));
}
:
{   // inside some function
    struct dnode *newnode = dnode_create(); // use
}
```

Or:

```
struct dnode *dnode_create (void);          // declare
:
{   // inside some function
    struct dnode *newnode = dnode_create(); // use
}
:
struct dnode *dnode_create (void) {         // define
    return calloc(1, sizeof(struct dnode));
}
```

You'll notice also that I've used `void` in the function declaration in both cases above. There's a subtle difference between that (no parameters) and the empty parameter list (an indeterminate number of parameters). You should use the former if you really want a parameter-less function.

Comment: I should cast calloc like (strcut dnode*)?

Comment: @Nob, no, don't cast `malloc/calloc` in C, it can hide certain subtle errors. Instead, make sure a prototype is defined at point of use.

Comment: I do include stdlib.h. What you mean by "declaring a prototype before you use it?"

Comment: @Nob, see the update. Given you include `stdlib.h`, it's probably your own function.

Comment: Sorry am still confused. Isnt that the first one is just the same one as mine? Or I have to use it within curly bracket?

Comment: @Nob, that depends. You show both those segments of code but it's unclear if you have them in that order in the _same_ translation unit (usually C source file). If they're in separate translation units, the prototype is not visible to the using area. I'll clarify that.